# findBy reference doctrine-mongodb

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.1, doctrine-mongodb

I have collections of users and posts.

User looks like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5089cc4c7b03b9902b000000"), "facebook_id" : "522128874" }
```

Post looks like

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("508aa21b7b03b9780800000f"), "facebook_id" : "10150709375878875", "user" : DBRef("User", ObjectId("5089cc4c7b03b9902b000000")), "message" : " Julia dream, dreamboat queen, queen of all my dreams", "updated_time" : 1333502938 }
```

I want to find all the posts of a specific user.

```
$user = $userRepo->findOneByFacebookId('522128874');
$posts = $postRepo->findOneByUser($user)
```

It doesn't work. I've also tried

```
$posts = $postRepo->findOneBy(array('user' => $user))
```

and

```
$posts = $postRepo->findOneBy(array('user' => $user->getId()))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you mapped your document relationships correctly, all you would need to do is just

```
$user = $userRepo->findOneByFacebookId($fbid);
$posts = $user->getPosts();
```

You might want to look at [Bidirectional References Doctrine Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/bidirectional-references.html)

If you want to find the posts of the user manually (the more tedious way), you have to create the method called findOneByUser($user) inside your Post repository. Then you will have to convert user ID to to a MongoId then use querybuilder to match user.$id field to the MongoId which will return cursor(s).

Remember, when you create a document (post in this case) that has reference to another document, it stores the reference via its MongoId, so you cannot simply just do findOneByUser($user) unless you have created this method yourself.

Comment: Thanks for adding detail to your answer, greatly helpful!

Answer (score 7):

**Bam!**

```
$posts = $postRepo->findOneBy(array('user.id' => $user->getId()))
```

Try that, worked for me. Would seem kinda stupid that you would have to query all elements.

Answer (score 0):

You must use the ***references()*** method of Query Builder for a *@ReferenceOne* like https://doctrine-mongodb-odm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder-api.html

```
$qb = $postRepo->createQueryBuilder('u')
               ->field('user')->references($user);
```

**PS**: use ***includesReferenceTo()*** a *@ReferenceMany*